# How to write a test in angular 2 to check if Input variable is set in Child component?

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

My app.component has a property called 'environment' which is set by using a http service ,below are the components

app.component.ts

```
//import ..

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: require('./app.component.html')
})

export class AppComponent {
  myEnvironment: String;
  workbenchBaseUrl : String = 'workbenchBaseUrl';

  constructor(private _propertyService : PropertyService){
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._propertyService.getValue(this.workbenchBaseUrl)
        .subscribe(environment => this.myEnvironment = environment,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }


}
```

Property service is an assynchorous Http  service which gives me the value of myEnviroment variable. I pass this variable to a child component i.e. workflow-display.component using one-way binding and the input decorator

This is how I pass it to the child component

app.component .html

```
  <!--container HTML hidden-->
    <main class="col-sm-9 offset-sm-3 col-md-10 offset-md-2 pt-3 mh-100">
        <workflow-display [environment] = "myEnvironment" #taskDisplay></workflow-display>
    </main>
  <!--container HTML hidden-->
```

workflow-display.component

```
    //import ..

    @Component({
        selector: 'workflow-display',
        template: require('./workflow-display.component.html')
    })
    export class WorkflowDisplayComponent implements OnInit {

        //some other variables hidden...
        workbenchTaskPage: string = 'wsIndex'; 
        @Input()
        environment: String;

        constructor(private _workflowService: WorkflowService) {

        }

        openTask(event: any, task: any) {
          window.open(this.environment + this.workbenchTaskPage + "?taskId=" + task.taskId + "&activitiWorkflow=true");
        }

 }
```

Now I am trying to write unit test for workdisplay.component to make sure it has its environment variable set , but I am not sure how I can test it as it is set only after the callback in the parent component and is undefined at first .
This is what I written in the spec so far

workflow-display.spec

```
//import..

describe('WorkflowDisplayComponent (inline template)', () => {

    let comp:    WorkflowDisplayComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<WorkflowDisplayComponent>;


    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ WorkflowDisplayComponent ], // declare the test component
            providers: [WorkflowService,
                        MockBackend,
                        BaseRequestOptions,
                        {
                        provide: Http,
                        deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions],
                        useFactory:
                            (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: BaseRequestOptions) => {
                                return new Http(backend, defaultOptions);
                            }
                        }
            ]
        }).compileComponents();

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(WorkflowDisplayComponent);

        comp = fixture.componentInstance; // BannerComponent test instance


    }));

    it('should have right URL', () => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect((comp.environment + comp.workbenchTaskPage)).toEqual('http://dev.grc.coreworkbench.int.westgroup.com/grcworkbench/app/grcnewsalerts/wsIndex');
    });
});
```

What i get when I run the test is this

```
should have right URL FAILED
        Expected 'undefinedwsIndex' to equal 'http://dev.grc.coreworkbench.int.westgroup.com/grcworkbench/app/grcnewsalerts/wsIndex'.
```

Now I see that the child components environment variable is not defined yet, I am not sure how I can get around this . Should test the app component instead to make sure its 'myEnvironment' variable is set or something else.

Comment: Did you get an answer?